# What do the French say for “Oh, you shouldn’t have”?

Tags: expressions, vocabulaire, expressions-idiomatiques

In English, this basically means that you’re politely declining a gift that you might feel embarrassed to get or that you don’t feel like you deserve. It can also be used humorously to say that you *do* deserve that gift.

Do the French have any common phrases for this situation?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Very close to the original English:

- Oh ! Vous n’auriez pas dû !
- Oh ! Tu n’aurais pas dû !

In the near vicinity → *It wasn’t necessary!* or close to *You didn’t have to!*

- Oh ! Il ne fallait pas !

Another common alternative → *You’ve done something crazy!*

- Vous avez fait une folie !
- Tu as fait une folie !